# Religion and beliefs

Tags: christianity

Why are people referring to Christian God and Muslim God as two different Gods? There is only one God. He is called by many names in different countries.

Comment: We can't really explain why "people" do what they do without at least some idea of who these "people" are.  As phrased, this question appears to be leading into a particular opinion rather than an actual practical question on the topic of Islam.  I would strongly suggest you check out the page in our help centre on "[What types of questions shouldn't I ask here?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)" as the Stack Exchange model is not particularly geared toward rhetorical questions and discussion topics.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason that Jews do not call Jesus God.  To a Muslim, the God that Christians believe in as God the Father is the same as the one they believe in, they just believe that the Christians have inaccurate views about the Godhood of Jesus and misunderstandings about the nature of God.

To a Christian however, the Islamic deity is not real, but rather a twisted perversion of God by a false prophet, thus, to a Christian, it is not the same.

Christians have a similar thing since they view their God the Father as the same as the Jewish God.  To Christian's the Old Testament is explained as God's demonstration that humans can not save themselves, no matter how much aid they are given by God.  He set a people apart, told them to kill anyone and anything that might get in their way, richly blessed them, and still they repeatedly failed to follow after God.

To Jews however, they see the law as the means to peace with God.  This results in significant differences in the way that Christian's and Jews see God, though Christians view the Jewish position as simply misunderstanding the same God, while Jews would see the Christian version of God as a fabrication.

Comment: "Christians have a similar thing since they view their God the Father as the same as the Jewish God" did Jews certify that "the Father" which you're talking about is the same "Lord God" of theirs? Or did they too tell the same thing, because "the Christianic deity or The Father is not real, but rather a twisted perversion of God by a false prophet"???

Comment: It's a bit interested and I can't really speak to the Jewish perspective.  Certainly Jews reject any clarifications about God the Father that are found in the New Testament, however Christianity is a bit different from Islam in that Christianity agrees with Jews about the veracity of the Old Testament/Torah.  We differ in interpretation of the prophecies, but hold the same prophecies and stories to be true.  Conversely, the Quran makes claims of significant difference from the narrative of the Old Testament/Torah, so is not really compatible in text or interpretation.

Comment: Overall though, it really is a bit of a shell doll type situation where each level of decedent religion views the others as close but slightly off where as the lower levels view the later versions as heretical.

Comment: If you want me to be honest, for a muslim, 
its an utterly balderdash statement to listen "The Father is not = Allah" 
just because of difference of one and only one single attribute, i.e. 
we believe [this](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%203%3A16-18&version=NIV) is 
odd one out, and hence not authentic, that's it. And about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incarnation_%28Christianity%29) 
we think it's a made up thing & we follow the [Unitarian style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitarian) still 
being [Christian](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/24125/11938).

Comment: and still worshiping the same "The Father" or what we call "Allah" 
Or entirely and the other way around, our beliefs completely match with that of Jews except for one thing 
i.e. 8th part in [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/24296/11938) and the Christian beliefs are what differing I can say.

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser - right, but if you read what the Quran states about Allah, it is theologically incompatible with what the Old Testament claims.  If you start looking at the differences between them, the stories are not even remotely similar.  They paint drastically different pictures, however it is hard to explain that clearly since Islam makes the claim of being very similar when in reality the view is not at all similar.

Comment: if u don't mind, can I request a simple example?

Comment: -1. As is, it seems the answer is written in a partially formed notion of biased opinions formed under the basic Christian doctrine and beliefs about the loving "The Father" without completely getting a picture of the violent "Lord God" of the Tanakh together which overlap the description of God in Qur'an.

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser - you are welcome to think that, but it isn't. Sorry about not getting back to you.  I've been busy and haven't had time to go back and look up specifics as I'm not an expert on Islamic theology, but I have read about 1/4 of the Quran and the stories are radically altered and the points made by them are quite opposite of both the Torah and the Christian NT.  I don't really have the time right now though.

Comment: I couldn't really find an online article about it I liked either as many of them are very Christo-centric, which is an easier case to make than that of the OT.  http://www.menorah.org/allahtrc.html seems to bring up several solid points that are Torah focused though and also logically consistent with both Christian and Jewish theology as well.

Comment: you probably missed something, I'm talking about the description of God. Not the stories of the prophets. Here is a nice e.g. if you're thinking about stories. I think Story of Noah of Qur'an is believed to have some problems by others, but it is not about the description of God. And to your article "Muslims insist that the name " Allah" must be used in every language;" [**NO**](http://quran.com/17/110), & seems article was written with words of hatred by Jews. There is no significance of word "Allah" except "Al-Ilah" which literally means "The God", and many more replies.

Comment: And that is what this original question was about "different names one God". And moreover, if you want some things to be clarified, plz & plz don't come with mindless stupid meaningless pointless articles written out of hatred or anger or meaningless criticism. plz don't mind. If you feel something is worth asking, even about the stories of prophets or anything else, sure, make it as a good question here, or maybe in chat later. All the best.

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser - yeah, like I said, there is a lot that isn't really good about the article and most of them are absolute garbage, but that one had a few decent points which was the best I could find on short notice.  I do realize that many of the points it brings up are rather poorly informed.

Comment: It's OK dear. Take your own time to understand. There's no hurry. But what I'm telling is, don't fall for stupid articles out there in the net. One good example, is asnwering-islam. Most of their articles are considered insane. If you wanna get the feel of Qur'an, first open your copy of Tanakh, understand it well, then read Qur'an. About the stories of Prophets, it depends..... plz feel free to remove some of the comments from here too.